# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'set' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, higher-order-functions

I keep getting the following error : `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'set' and 'tuple'`, which i am not sure why?

Here is my code:

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y: x<y, set(list(map(tuple,list1))), set(list(map(tuple,list2)))))
```

Comment: That does definitely not look simpler to me.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, a possible simplification could be:

```
set(map(tuple, list1)).issubset(set(map(tuple, list2)))
```

Or using your notation:

```
set(map(tuple, list1)) < set(map(tuple, list2))
```

---

Some remarks:

- No need to build those intermediate lists. `set` can take an iterable, just as `list` does
- You only need  to check if a set is a subset of the other once. Reduce doesn't really make sense here

Comment: I dont want to use issubset function, and the point of reduce here was to return a boolean

Comment: This returns a boolean. and subset is the same as `<` @misu